# Перехват трафика провайдером

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, vpn, провайдер

(несколько нехороших слов) МТС/Vodafone Украина перехватывает 404 ошибки и делает редирект на свою рекламу, подсовывая мне зачем-то на ПК файлы для Андроида.

В результате я не могу нормально отладить сайт.

Думал, подниму VPN и решу проблему, но и после этого идет редирект. Но вроде только с IP моего сервера. В чем причина и как от этого избавится?

Comment: Использовать https?

Comment: Ага, наверно очень интересно будет для всех сайтов, с которыми я ежедневно разбираюсь еще и https поднимать...

Comment: @AlexZ, `Let's Encrypt`?

Comment: Та же проблема. Если удалось решить, подскажите как.